# How to format JSON for Google Charts from C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to output JSON from c# for use with a google Chart.

At the moment I build it using JSON.Net:

```
  JArray arrB =     new JArray(
                        from c in cards
                        where c.complete
                               group c by new { date = Convert.ToDateTime(c.completed).Date } into g
                               select new JObject(
                                   new JProperty("date", g.Key.date),
                                   new JProperty("completedHours", g.Sum(x => x.estHours))
                                   ) 
                        );
```

Which outputs the following:

```
 { "burndown" : [ { "completedHours" : 30.0,
[ { "completedHours" : 30.0,
    "date" : "2014-03-26T00:00:00+00:00"
  },
  { "completedHours" : 3.0,
    "date" : "2014-04-03T00:00:00+01:00"
  },
  { "completedHours" : 3.0,
    "date" : "2014-03-28T00:00:00+00:00"
  },
  { "completedHours" : 1.0,
    "date" : "2014-03-27T00:00:00+00:00"
  }
]
```

However, google charts doesn't like this. As far as I can work out I need to format it so it has column headings in the first block of data, and then content after. I'm new to JSON so not sure how to go about this.

EDIT: Adding "correct" structure

As far as I can tell from the Google Charts documentation, the correct format should be like this:

```
{"cols":[{"id":"Col1","label":"","type":"date"}],
  "rows":[
    {"c":[{"v":"a"},{"v":"Date(2010,10,6)"}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"b"},{"v":"Date(2010,10,7)"}]}
  ]
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Comment: If you get the Newtonsoft JSON package from nuGet, you can just create whatever object structure you want, and then use that library to encode it to a JSON string. That should take all of the guesswork and "I'm new to JSON" out of the equation for you.

Comment: Could you update your question with the desired JSON structure for output?

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm using - not sure how I change the format of the string as by default it encodes it as above. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: As @YuvalItzchakov said, if you have a sample of the JSON it's expecting, it'll be a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your JSON schema, your object hierarchy needs to look like this:

```
public class Col
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string v { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    public List<C> c { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Col> cols { get; set; }
    public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
}
```

So, to construct your json, you would do something like this:

```
var rootObject = new RootObject()
{
    cols = new List<Col>
    {
        new Col {id = "1", label = "2", type = "string"}
    },
    rows = new List<Row>()
    {
        new Row 
        {
           c = new List<C> { 
               new C { v = "a" },
               new C { v = "b"}
           }
        }
    }
};
```